# Windows Photo Viewer Some Picture Printing Result Invert Colour

Tags: windows-7, printing, printer, windows-photo-viewer

I have a quite interesting problem of Windows 7 photo viewer. I noticed the program printing some of images in  inverted state. Do not know the cause, I tried print it using other program without problem, also make sure the printer setting was correct (the problem occurred on all printer).

Any suggestion issue would be really helpful because I do not want to reinstall the operating system due to this issue.

[image: Attached File]

Comment: I searched for `windows photo viewer inverted colors` and [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2415238) was the first result.

Comment: Yeah this is definitely my first case encounter the problem as well. Worst case I will reinstall the Windows operating system to fix such issue.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:
Control panel > Color management > Advanced Tab
Set Device Profile to sRGB IEC1966

Answer (score 1):

Not certain this is the same problem, but I can reproduce a similar effect as follows:

Once the 'print pictures' window with the little preview appears, click [options] ( lower right ). Click 'Color Management'. Click [Advanced] tab. Make sure the various settings are correct.

For example, by changing 'Device Profile' to 'Agfa Swop Standard', I can get a similar effect to the one you describe.

Either way, it may be worth checking the settings on this page. Mine are all listed as "System Default (xxxxx)" where xxxxx varies depending upon the category.

Not certain, but hope it helps.